# Situations when recursion helps

Tags: tips, recursion

Recursion is actually quite powerful, sometimes its doesn't look like that child problem of itself exist, but recursion is just helpful.

One case per answer.

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand the actual question or goal here.  Is this supposed to be some kind of meme?  I don't see how anyone can answer this, or how it would be rated.

Comment: @Beska [tips questions are for collecting helpful tips for golfing in an particular language. Sometimes it's also used for tips for a certain type of challenge or for asking how to handle a commonly-occurring situation in a language.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/tips/info)

Comment: Helpful for what?

Comment: @WheatWizard For whatever, though more likely [tag:code-golf]

Answer (score 6):

## Adjusting argument order

E.g. Decide if 3 sticks construct a right triangle:

```
(a,b,c)=>a*a+b*b==c*c|b*b+c*c==a*a|c*c+a*a==b*b  // 47 bytes
f=(a,b,c)=>a<b|a<c?f(b,c,a):a*a==b*b+c*c         // 40 bytes
```

(Yeah the `hypot` solution is also 40, but it's not the point here)

Here it rotates until `a` is one of the largest elements, and there's no need to write the formula three times.

Answer (score 2):

## Another branch of function happens to fit

In Infinite Turtle, all numbers are between 0 and 100, inclusive. There's only saturated increment and decrement by one operation, and isZero condition. Requires to subtract modulo 101.

My solution:

```
SUB101(x,y) := y==0?x:SUB101(x==0?GEN100(x):x-1,y-1)
GEN100(x) := SUB101(x+1,x)==0?x:GEN100(x+1)
```

Here, `SUB101(x+1,x)` returns 1 if `x!=100`, or 0 if `x==100`. `GEN100` is never called inside due to input limit. By reusing `SUB101`, I needn't another `SUB` or `ISEQUAL`.

[image][image]